# Chained Select for sub-boards

Tags: php, sql, select

I've written this code:

```
<select id="board_id" name="board_id" class="select_class">
<?php $userId  = $this->session->userdata('login_user_id');?>
<?php $userBoards   = getUserBoard($userId);?>
<?php foreach ($userBoards as $boardKey => $boardValues):?>
<option value="<?php echo $boardValues->id;?>"><?php echo $boardValues->board_name;?>    </option>
<?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

It logs the user and displays a dropdown list of that users boards.
I have sub-boards too. It displays them all.
I'm trying to modify this code to display just sub-boards, or at least mark sub-boards differently so the user knows which is which. Currently it lists them all by time of creation, regardless of board/sub-board status.

The column in SQL which tells me if the board is sub or not is `sub`. If the board is sub the id of the parent board is the value in this column `$boardValues->id`.

I originally wanted chained select to do this but it was too difficult to grasp and wouldn't work on my website.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `optgroup` html tag to differentiate between boards and sub-boards.

[see example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)

In other way you can use `text-indent` style for sub-boards option to display differently.

Comment: I guess I could make each board a group and then each sub-board an option within the group.

Comment: yes you can do the same, if this answer works for you please vote/accept this.